# Angular bootstrap - accordion shows content when closed

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angular-bootstrap

This seems pretty straight forward but I don't understand why this accordion menu is always showing the content, before the header is clicked. I'm stuck using version 0.13.0 for now.

```
<accordion close-others="true">
<accordion-group heading="{{ config.vin }}" ng-model="config.vin" ng-repeat="config in vm.accessor.customConfigs track by config.vin">
<p>hello</p> // always visible
</accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: There's nothing explicitly special about the `p` tag that would lead me to believe that it *should* be hidden...

Comment: you need to set configs to your accordion [ui-bootstrap accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion); i think you have to set [is-open="false"] for all your array

Comment: is-open="false" is the default.

Comment: The content should be hidden unless is-open="true"